# After removing sprite from screen I cannot spawn it back in - Swift, SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want to spawn a sprite onto the screen every 3 seconds, and after collision I want the sprite to be removed from the screen. Whenever the sprite is removed from screen it does not return to the screen.

Here is the spawn code:

in DidMoveToView:

```
var presentSpawnTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(presentSpawnSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("addPresent"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

>

```
func addPresent() {
    var presentSpriteImage: String!

    // Set the present's initial coordinates
    var presentSpawnY: CGFloat!
    var presentEndY: CGFloat!

    presentSpawnY = frame.size.width + (present.size.height / 2)
    presentEndY = -(present.size.height / 2)

    let minSpawnX = frame.size.width / 3
    let maxSpawnX = (frame.size.width * 0.9) - present.size.width / 2
    let spawnXRange = UInt32(maxSpawnX - minSpawnX)
    let presentSpawnX = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnXRange)) + minSpawnX
    present.position = CGPoint(x: presentSpawnX, y: presentSpawnY)

    addChild(present)

    // Set the present's speed
    let minMoveTime = 2
    let maxMoveTime = 3
    let moveTimeRange = maxMoveTime - minMoveTime
    let moveTime = NSTimeInterval((Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(moveTimeRange))) + minMoveTime))

    // Send the present on its way
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveToY(presentEndY, duration: moveTime)
    let cleanUpAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    present.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction, cleanUpAction]))
}
```

The code that removes the sprite from screen:

```
func presentDidCollideWithSprite(present:SKSpriteNode, sprite:SKSpriteNode) {
    self.present.removeFromParent()
    score += 1
    NSLog("Score: \(score)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a new SKSpriteNode everytime you call the `addPresent`-method. You don't have to worry about memory-management. Swift can handle that itself. Just don't forget to remove it from the screen.

Comment: I am already calling addChild(present), how else would I go about doing this?

Comment: But you call it on an already existing node. Just try to instantiate a new sprite each time and add it.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?